# CSS Rule not working no Matter what i tried

Tags: css, woocommerce, css-selectors, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a problem that i try to change somthing in my site and no matter whhat i try its still there

Rule :

`.woocommerce form .form-row-wide, .woocommerce-page form .form-row-wide { clear: both; }`

Change:

`.woocommerce form .form-row-wide, .woocommerce-page form .form-row-wide { clear: inherit!important; }`

Don't work :

1. i tried from the customize
2. through the the actual path of the css
3. try to delete the all section
4. tried in min.css and regular.css

Path:

https://obeyyourbody.com/wp-content/themes/astra/assets/css/minified/compatibility/woocommerce/woocommerce-grid.min.css?ver=3.9.2

Checkout Page for the issue:

https://obeyyourbody.com/checkout/

Comment: Your rule selects the elements fine, but since `inherit` is not a valid value for the `clear` property, it doesn't apply. The fact that this gets crossed out when you inspect the element's style via dev tools, could have already told you that.

Comment: Tnx, so do you have any suggestions how can I clear/delete it ?

Comment: You can use 'unset' value.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend you to be more verbose in your question. That will be beneficial for both the potential answerer and you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.